# design a updatable immutable class

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a simple class defined as :

```
class M () {
  val map = Map()
}
```

in this case the map is immutable, without changing that, can I make it possible to add values to the map?

```
class M () {
  val map: Map[Int, Int] = Map()

  def setValue(key: Int, value: Int)
}
```

is this possible with immutable?

I know that you can do tricks like copy the object, but that make the usage like :

```
val test: M = new M()
val test1: M = test.setValue(2,3)
```

is there a way so I can do :
    val test: M = new M()
    test.setValue(1,2)
    test.setValue(2,3)

or the only way is to change the map to mutable?

Comment: Mutable means updatable.  So you're asking for a mutable immutable class.  It can only be one or the other.  serejja and Kigyo, in their answers, gave your only two options when dealing with an immutable object.  That's just how they work.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can go fully immutable -- this way setValue will yield new instance of M class:

```
class M(val map: Map[Int, Int] = Map()) {
  def setValue(key: Int, value: Int) = new M(map + (key -> value))
}
```

Does not makes much sense put alone, but there might be a reasons for such solutions.

2) If you're strictly for keeping map defined as val, not var - use mutable Map:

```
import collection.mutable.{Map => MMap}
class M() {
  val map: MMap[Int, Int] = MMap()
  def setValue(key: Int, value: Int) = map += (key -> value)
}
```

3) Finally, you can use var, just like others pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
class M[A, B](val map: Map[A, B]) {

  def this() = this(Map.empty[A,B])

  def setValue(a: A, b: B) = new M[A, B](map + (a -> b))
}
```

To get a new M you can either create one with the constructor or use setValue to create a new M with the updated Map.

Example:

```
val test = new M[Int, Int]()
println(test.map) //Map()
val test1 = test.setValue(2, 3)
println(test1.map) //Map(2 -> 3)
```

Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: that's what i want to avoid, basically now you have to create a new variable to take this newly created object, also it is confusing when you call setValue but can't change the original object.

Comment: @user776635 You don't want an mutable map, you don't want a var, you don't want to create a new object. How on earth do you expect this to work out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a whole point of immutability - any potentially "mutable" operation creates a new object instead of modifying an existing one. So you probably wanna make your `map` a `var`, not a `val` so that it would look like that:

```
class M () {
  var map: Map[Int, Int] = Map()

  def setValue(key: Int, value: Int): map = map + (a -> b)
}
```

Comment: I am hoping to find a way to avoid var.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a way to populate the map on creation and have it immutable afterwards? If so, you can pass the values through `M`'s constructor:

```
class M(values:(Int,Int)*) {
  val map = Map(values:_*)
}

val test = new M((1,2), (2,3)) // or new M(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)
```